# how to see what is happening in an init.d script?

Tags: bash

Something is going wrong in a script and I cannot find a way to view what is happening.

something wrong here whether I put quotes about the  "$DAEMON_OPTS" or leave them out

script

```
start-stop-daemon ...  --exec $DAEMON -- "$DAEMON_OPTS"
```

my options are not being passed or if they are passed they are ignored

I tried to echo as in

```
echo '--exec $DAEMON -- "$DAEMON_OPTS"'
```

but nothing was echo'ed  I also tried redirecting the echo as in

```
echo ... >> /home/username/writeablefile.txt
```

that did not work

tried

```
let mytest='--exec $DAEMON -- "$DAEMON_OPTS"'
------and-----
mytest='--exec $DAEMON -- "$DAEMON_OPTS"'
```

but mytest was undefined after script exited

with and w/o the quotes about the DAEMON_OPTS

I grep'ed through var/log but found nothing useful.

Would like to expand the options to see exactly what is passed to the executing program.  Not sure how to do that.

Comment: did you try to run it manually with `bash -xv` or `sh -xv`

Comment: I will try that but in the meantime the entire problem is MOOT.  It turns out that a file in /systemd/system/stupid_file_i_forgot_about.service is what starts up the app and that service file does not have a place for an argument so the script I am trying to debug seemingly cannot pass any arguments anyway.  IMHO of course and I am wrong a lot.